# Displaying the image in other div - wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i want to display the image of posts in other div then content's one.

I mean like this.

```
<div class="latest-posts">
    <div class="latest-posts-info">
        <div class="title"><h1>HERE IS TITLE<h1></div>
        <div class="text">HERE IS CONTENT</div>
        <a href="#" class="read-more">Read more...</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="latest-posts-img">HERE I WANT THE IMAGE</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

While was adding a post in wp admin, i noticed its the only way, displaying image IN content.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the Php code of your post loop?

Comment: What is your actual need?

Comment: I dont have any php loop yet, i'm actually reading how to do it.

Comment: We can't do anything with this if you don't post the PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

```
<div class="latest-posts-img"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a custom template for this post using this function: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image